# Help with controlling digital pot with qdial using python

Tags: python, qt

I have a program that controls digital pots using push buttons on a qt GUI which work well.  I am trying to modify the program to use qdials but can't figure out how to program it other than either dial-up resistance of the pot or dial-down resistance.  It's either one or the other.  I will post the code below and was hoping someone might be able to give me some guidance.

Hope this was posted in the right place.

```
self.IHTA_dial.valueChanged.connect(self.IHTAdown)
self.IHTA_dial.valueChanged.connect(self.IHTAup)
self.IHTA_dial.setNotchesVisible(True)

self.resist_val_OHTB = 8
self.dim_step = 1
self.dim_command = int("0001", 36)
self.OHTBupdate()

self.resist_val_IHTB = 8
self.dim_step = 1
self.dim_command = int("0001", 36)
self.IHTBupdate()

def IHTAupdate(self):
    IHTA_pot.put(self.dim_command | self.resist_val_IHTA, bits=16)

def IHTAup(self):       
    self.resist_val_IHTA= max(0, self.resist_val_IHTA - self.dim_step)
    self.dim_step = 2
    self.dim_command = 0x11 << 36
    self.IHTAupdate() 

def IHTAdown(self): 
    self.resist_val_IHTA = min(256, self.resist_val_IHTA + self.dim_step)
    self.dim_step = 2
    self.dim_command = 0x11 << 36
    self.IHTAupdate()
```

The above code works with the push buttons.  I have tried many different combinations of different things but I'm just guessing at this point and need help so I can learn.

I'm sure some of this is not correct, I am pretty new at this so any advise would be appreciated.

I'm using a Raspberry pi 3 running python 2.7.9 and Qt version 4.8.6.

Let me know if you need any other info.  Thank you.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to the question and answer which makes it off topic for this site.

Comment: Understood.  Wasn't sure.  Thanks.  Can I move it or does a moderator do that?  And where should it go?

Comment: @kjohns As a mod we do have the ability to migrate a question to another site, where you will need to become a member to continue editing the question, responding to comments, e.t.c... Your question should probably be moved StackOverflow as its coding related.

Comment: I am a member of StackOverflow and its there now, thank you.  I will pay more attention to that in the future.