# Using qdial to control digital potentiometers

Tags: python, qt

I have a python program that controls digital pots using push buttons on a qt GUI which work well. I am trying to modify the program to use qdials but can't figure out how to program it other than either dial-up resistance of the pot or dial-down resistance. It's either one or the other. I will post the code below and was hoping someone might be able to give me some guidance.

Hope this was posted in the right place.

```
    self.IHTA_dial.valueChanged.connect(self.IHTAdown)
    self.IHTA_dial.valueChanged.connect(self.IHTAup)
    self.IHTA_dial.setNotchesVisible(True)

    self.resist_val_OHTB = 8
    self.dim_step = 1
    self.dim_command = int("0001", 36)
    self.OHTBupdate()

    self.resist_val_IHTB = 8
    self.dim_step = 1
    self.dim_command = int("0001", 36)
    self.IHTBupdate()

def IHTAupdate(self):
    IHTA_pot.put(self.dim_command | self.resist_val_IHTA, bits=16)

def IHTAup(self):       
    self.resist_val_IHTA= max(0, self.resist_val_IHTA - self.dim_step)
    self.dim_step = 2
    self.dim_command = 0x11 << 36
    self.IHTAupdate() 

def IHTAdown(self): 
    self.resist_val_IHTA = min(256, self.resist_val_IHTA + self.dim_step)
    self.dim_step = 2
    self.dim_command = 0x11 << 36
    self.IHTAupdate()
```

The above code works with the push buttons. I have tried many different combinations of different things but I'm just guessing at this point and need help so I can learn.

I'm sure some of this is not correct, I am pretty new at this so any advise would be appreciated.

I'm using a Raspberry pi 3 running python 2.7.9 and Qt version 4.8.6.

Let me know if you need any other info. Thank you.

Comment: What is the difference with your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517385/help-with-controlling-digital-pot-with-qdial-using-python ?

Comment: No difference.  Wrong forum I was told so I moved to a more proper forum.

Comment: then eliminate this question, it is already a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, this question on StackExhange has been deleted.  Still learning the etiquette of these forums.  Thanks.